# Replace individual Matches in a regex result

Tags: c#, regex

I'm preparing an HTML formatted email. Images must be bundled in multipart mime, and references rewritten. Template HTML is in a file, and I've written a regex to find filenames:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("ApproveUserTemplate.html"))
  html = sr.ReadToEnd();
var matches = Regex.Matches(html, "\\s*img\\s+src\\s*=[\"'](.*.\\w{3})[\"']");
```

The expression matches, and the parentheses cause a group to be captured. So for a file containing `<img src="blort.png" />` I get a match that has three groups, where match.Groups[1].Value returns the string "blort.png".

So far, so good, but what I don't see from the documentation in msdn is how you go about *replacing* values. In this case I want to replace `blort.png` with `cid:blortguid` (I construct a name table mapping the file name to a GUID identifying a linked resource).

I can't just do a bulk substitution in a single operation because I need to loop through the matches, progressively building a name table, constructing LinkedResource instances and adding them to the message AlternateView object. The replacement values don't even exist until the resources have been created and assigned ContentIds.

There is a mechanism for obtaining a collection of Matches. I was hoping to iterate this, do the associated admin, compute the replacement value and perform the replacement just on that particular match.

How can I perform a replacement on a specific Match instance?

If that's not a supported model, what's the point of surfacing a collection of Match objects?

Comment: There's a replace method on Regex from memory? Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that the iterative use I describe in the question is not possible.

However, for the case described there are some advantages to using two passes:

1. Iterate Matches. When a name is not already in the name table, create a linked resource, add it to the message.
2. Iterate the name table. Use string.Replace to swap each filename for the corresponding cid:resourceid obtained from the name table.

Doing it like this makes it straightforward to use a single copy of a resource linked more than once.